# Cannot fix my Navbar when rolling the page

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm new to HTML and CSS, and I'm having issues with my nav bar. I cannot appoint my Navbar on top of the page when scrolling through the sections, and when I finally solve my question, the hover effects inside my sections stop working. Anyone here knows how to fix this ?

Here is my code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html{
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
body{
    font-family: "Walkway Black";
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    perspective: 1.1px;
}
nav {
    float:right;
    z-index: 2;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:90;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:60px;        /* distanciamento de cada palavra*/
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

nav a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;  /*texto em letra maiuscula*/
    font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #444;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}
#secao1{
    display: flex;
 background-image:url(../imagens/intro_cloud.png);
    background-position:center;
 background-size:cover;
    z-index:1;
}

#secao2{
    display: flex;
 background-image: url(../imagens/image4.png);
 background-size: cover;
 transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
 z-index: 0;
}

#secao3{
    display:flex;
 background-image: url(../imagens/image2.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
    z-index:1;
}
.slide{
 display: flex;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    justify-content: center;
 position:relative;
 padding: 25% 10%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 transform-style: inherit;
    overflow: auto;
}
#box {                          /*box*/
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:15%;
 width: 880px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 15px auto;
 display: flex;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#box:after {                       /*efeito box*/
 display: flex;
 content: '.';
 line-height: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.estilo {
 display: flex;
 width: 880px;
 list-style: none;
}
.estilo li {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 float: left;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 margin:20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.estilo li img {
    border-radius: 15%;
 width: 80%;
 height: 80%;
 display: flex;
 z-index: 999;
 position: absolute;
 transition:.5s;
    border:-2px;
}
.conteudo {
 display: flex;
 width: 80%;
 height: 80px;
 background-color:#363739;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;
    opacity:.5;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 160px;
}
.estilo li:hover img {               /*efeito bloco*/
 margin-top:-80px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alt</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
<body> 
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Equipe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Orçamento</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section id="secao1" class="slide">

</section>
<section id="secao2" class="slide">
  <div id="box">
   <ul class="estilo">
       <li>
           <img src="../código/imagens/giphy.gif" alt="">
           <div class="conteudo"></div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="../código/imagens/systems.gif" alt="">
           <div class="conteudo"></div>
       </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="secao3" class="slide"></section>

</body>
</html>
```

PS.: Hope you understand the problem.

Comment: I've seen that the `perspective` is making it not work, somehow. But there are a lot of wrong coding, like missing units and such. For example, your `right: 90` is missing its unit in your `nav`. Should it be `90px`?

Comment: Nice man ! You got it! And about the "right: 90", I have not seen it... Thank you =D

Comment: Leon Freire, Is there any way I can resolve this without removing the perspective ?

Comment: I have never actually seen `perspective` in use, so I can't really say why that is happening.